# React Sub views in View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Im using ReactJS with React-Router for a dashboard style application.

**App.js**

```
  <div>
    <Toolbar/>
    <RouteHandler lang={this.state.lang} account={this.state.account} logout={this.handleLogout} validate={this.handleValidate} />
  </div>
```

This is what the main file looks like, first the user has to login, so I don't want to display stuff like the sidebar. But if I login I want to go to the home view that's styled entirely differently. Inside this view I now want a sub-view because I don't want to add these divs & components to each new route I make.

**Home.js**

```
<div id="main">   
    <div id="left">
        <Logo />
        <Sidemenu />
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <Smallmenu />
        <Bigmenu />
        <!-- View needs to be here now -->
    </div>

    <Footer />
</div>
```

I've looked for sub-routes and nested views but I couldn't find anything I'm looking for.

Whats the best way to accomplish this double view thingy?

Edit:
React & react-router version 0.13.3

Comment: Have you looked at react-router 1.0? In 1.0, `Route` takes a `components` (plural) prop and your components just use `this.props.children` instead of `RouteHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't dig deep enough into react-router. It's actually pretty easy to do this nested routing.

```
var routes = (
    <Route name="App" path="/" handler={require('./components/App.jsx')}>

        <DefaultRoute handler={require('./components/LoginPage.jsx')} />    

        <Route name="Main" handler={require('./components/MainPage.jsx')}>
            <DefaultRoute handler={require('./components/views/News.jsx')} />
            <NotFoundRoute handler={require('./components/views/NotFound.jsx')} />
        </Route>

        <NotFoundRoute handler={require('./components/NotFoundPage.jsx')} />

    </Route>

);
```

You can add a route with new subroutes this way, and in the main component you need to add another RouteHandler tag so the route handler knows where to place the views.